# Chai Cannot read property 'should' of null

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, knex.js

I'm getting the following error when unit testing for a single item using [knex](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex). I'm also referencing this https://mherman.org/blog/test-driven-development-with-node/

It renders api/users/1 successfully. So not sure why it says null.

> GET /api/users/:id
>          Should return a single show :
>        Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'should' of null
>         at should (tests/users.spec.js:59:26)

**users.spec.js**

```
import chai from 'chai';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import { assert } from 'assert'
import users from '../routes/users';
import request from 'supertest';


describe('GET /api/users/:id ', () =>{
    it('Should return a single show ', (done)=> {
       chai.request(users)
            .get('/users/1')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .end((response) => {
                // error begins here
                response.should.have.status(200);
                response.should.be.json; 
                response.body.should.be.a('object');
                response.body.should.have.property('id');
                response.body.name.should.equal(1);
                done()
            })          

    });
})
```

**routes/users.js**

```
users.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
    return knex('users').where({id: req.params.id})
        .then( (user) => {
            res.json({
                user: user
            })
        });
})
```

Comment: According to the docs, you need to write `expect(response).to.have.status(200)`, so you should follow official documentation instead of a 3 years old blog post: https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http

Comment: what about everything else ?

Comment: i get  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'status' in null` when using `expect(response).to.have.status(200);`

Comment: read the whole documentation, your tutorial is outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing `expect` from `chai` instead of `should`. You can either change:

`response.should.have.status(200);` to `expect(response).to.have.status(200);` (do this for all your should statements)

or import should by changing:

`import { expect } from 'chai';` to `import { should } from 'chai';`

Hope that helps!